# Which components should I have inside App.js?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, components, jsx

I have learned react recently and I wonder if the code example below is a good practice?

I have the navbars etc in `Header` wrapped in a `<header>` tag, `Main` in a `<main>` tag and so on. Is this how It should be done?

```
export const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Main />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends your project , maybe some component , you dont need header or footer .
so you most ,put Header and Footer inside the main

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start if you only have one page, otherwise you have to use react-router-dom and adapt your components: the header and footer don't change, just the "main" section...

Also in your example, remove the first div, it is useless:

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

or

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

If you want to see an example with react-router-dom: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kcxqzh?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 0):

Your question probably refers to the semantics of the HTML structure

Once that React structure already includes **body**, this div isn't needed as a semantic element. You can remove it by just replacing by a **Fragment**

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

If you're interested, you can read more about HTML semantic at: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Semantics

[image]